# If you have a long output of text over multiple pages, is there a way to lock a certain line to be visible?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to print a large amount of text, the console will keep only the last lines of the text on screen. 
I'm looking for a way to lock a line, lets say line 1 and I want it to be the first line on screen and then scroll down to see the end of the text.

Hope I explained it well enough.

EDIT: Failed to say, that I want to do this in a python script.

Comment: How is this Python and/or programming related?

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I wanted to do this within a python script. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do that from a python script, and that's why this is tagged with `python`.

You want to emulate the behavior of the command `less` or `more`. You need to use something like `curses` for that: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do from a python script. I appreciate your comment and will check it out. Thanks!